# How to use light theme for android in titanium

Tags: android, titanium

How can I change it so that android uses a light theme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your project and then copy `<app>/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml` to `<app>/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the theme in.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme

Precisely:

```
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this automatically? Or, do I need to do this each time I build?

Comment: Build 1 time so it auto generates the AndroidManifest.xml, then you move the file from build to platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml which will not be overwritten.